# replace a vowel in string with its successor example snow will become snpw

Tags: java

I have been given a question in which a vowel has to be replaced with predecessor. Example: `"snow"` should be retuned as `"snpw"`

```
import java.util.*;
class voweladd
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter String pls:");
        String str = in.nextLine();
        char b ;

        StringBuilder a = new StringBuilder(str);
        for(int i =0;i<str.length();i++)
        {
            if((str.charAt(i)=='a')||(str.charAt(i)=='e')||(str.charAt(i)=='i')||(str.charAt(i)=='o')||(str.charAt(i)=='u'))
            {
                b = str.charAt(i);
                b +=1;
                char temp;
                temp = b;
                b = str.charAt(i);
                a.setCharAt(i,temp);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("New STring is:"+str);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to give more information to go off. What exactly is going wrong? Do you have an error output? Please give as much useful information as you can, otherwise your question will probably be downvoted for laziness

Comment: All the best for your exams ;)

Comment: By the way, is it the predecessor or the successor? Because `b+=1` takes the successor: `o` becomes `p`, like in your example but not in your text.

Comment: Also, define "vowel". Is `"y"` a vowel?

Comment: no y is nota vowel and its the successor

Comment: bhargav rao thankyou for the wishes

Comment: yassin your technique works and it is doing the right thing but can u explai n me the logic pls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not print `str` which value's never changed.

Try to print the `StringBuffer's` object because it contains the replacements.

```
System.out.println("New STring is:"+a.toString());
```

Thanks to @Blip, I did not notice another problem. You added character to the StringBuffer's object only if the input is a vowel.

Here is what your if test should look like :

```
if((str.charAt(i)=='a')||(str.charAt(i)=='e')||(str.charAt(i)=='i')||(str.charAt(i)=='o')||(str.charAt(i)=='u'))
{
    b = str.charAt(i);
    b +=1;
    char temp;
    temp = b;
    b = str.charAt(i);
    a.setCharAt(i,temp);
    continue;
}
a.setCharAt(i, str.charAt(i));
```

---

### Input-Output

`aeiou` -> `bfjpv`

---

That said, here is a changing of your code, easier to write and understand

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter String pls:");
String str = in.nextLine();
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
for (char c : str.toCharArray()){
    if ("aeiou".contains(""+c)){
        output.append((char)(c+1));
    } else {
        output.append(""+c);
    }
}
System.out.println(output.toString());
```

Comment: there is a problem with your solution. if the original string was **abcd** the output will be **b** or if it were **map** the output would be **b**

Comment: @Blip Why would that be a problem? That is exactly what OP is trying to do

Comment: @Blip Thank you very much Blip, I changed the answer.

Comment: @Smittey like in the question itself the OP wants **snow** to become **snpw** but if the `StringBuffer` variable `a.toString()` is outputted, without changing the code then the output would be just **p**

Comment: yassin can u explain me the logic pls cuz im having  a tough time understanding it